# Unable to load a file from drawables- open CV

Tags: android, opencv

I have my image file under drawable folder, I am trying to read the image to process it further.This is the method I am using ,image.width() always return 0,I am not getting any errors in the log cat.

```
public Mat loadImageFromFile(String fileName) {

        Mat rgbLoadedImage = null;

        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(root, fileName);

        // this should be in BGR format according to the
        // documentation.
        Mat image = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath());

        if (image.width() > 0) {

            rgbLoadedImage = new Mat(image.size(), image.type());

            Imgproc.cvtColor(image, rgbLoadedImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);

            if (DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "loadedImage: " + "chans: " + image.channels()
                        + ", (" + image.width() + ", " + image.height() + ")");

            image.release();
            image = null;
        }
        return rgbLoadedImage;

    }
```

I am calling this method after open CV has been loaded

```
private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully...................");
                    loadImageFromFile("pedestrian");

                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };
```

I have also tried  `Mat m = Highgui.imread("/pedestrian");` here also m.width() is 0.

Comment: Your code is reading from external storage directory. What has that to do with the drawable folder?

Comment: cehck if `file.getAbsolutePath()` is not null

Comment: @greenapps how do I read it from drawable folder?

Comment: If you would google for 'android how to read from drawable'.

Comment: @greenapps In open CV this is how they do  Mat m = Highgui.imread("/pedestrian");

Comment: Then don't listen to me as i know nothing of open CV. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works ,

```
Mat img = Utils.loadResource(context, R.drawable.pedestrian, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```